# Is this a "color" or "colored" background?

Tags: word-usage

color could be an adjective.

> [color](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/color)
>
> showing things in all their colors, not just black and
>
> white color photos

I also see **colored** things, e.g. a rainbow **colored** background

[image]

Is it still idiomatic if I substitute "color" for "colored"?

> a rainbow **color** background

Answer (score -1):

No you can't use color. You must use rainbow colored background. Color is just a noun. You are using the word color as adjective in background. Also one more note: in British english it is written as 'colour'.

Comment: This is actually a correct answer in this case.  I'm not sure, but I assume it was downvoted because it doesn't address the adjective form of "color" which the OP quoted the dictionary definition for, so it would probably be worth explaining that "color" can be used as an adjective in cases like "color photographs", but there it means something different ("color" vs. "black-and-white").